# Why it doesn't show media urls on rest Api? (Wordpress)

Tags: images, media, rest-api

Im using Listable theme on my website and Rest Api because im developing the Android App. I need to show on the rest api the url links of my listings but they doesn't show. For example here:
http://buscadorcordoba.com.ar/wp-json/wp/v2/job_listing/12380
It just says "main_image":["12382,12383,12384"] ...
A strange thing is that when a user request to add their listing and i accept the request via another form, the media`s urls show correctly. For example here? http://buscadorcordoba.com.ar/wp-json/wp/v2/job_listing/12374

Can you help me please? I don't know how to do it

Sorry for my English! Thank You